# A consequence of theorem 2.1.9 in Bartle & Sherbert.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove that if a,b $\in \mathbb{R},$such that $a \leq b + \epsilon,$ for every $\epsilon > 0,$then $a \leq b.$

The theorem is in the following image:

[image]

Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Suppose $a > b$ and try to obtain a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a > b$ then there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ for which $a = b + \varepsilon$.

Note that $\varepsilon > \varepsilon/2$; so, $a = b + \varepsilon > b + \varepsilon/2$.

But the inequality $a > b + \varepsilon/2$ violates the given that $a \leq b + \epsilon$ for $\epsilon = \varepsilon/2$.

Comment: Unsure why somebody would downvote this, and I can't fathom why somebody would downvote this while leaving no comment...I've upvoted to compensate - noting it appears to me to be both correct and concise.

Comment: @David Thanks! I've gotten a few recently; it would really be nice if downvoters would explain themselves. My *guess* is that what I wrote here is too similar to the textbook excerpt in the OP and/or the comment left on the OP... **Or:** Someone is having a rough day, in which case: I hope their downvoting me brightened things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $b<a$ then we have that $0 < a - b$, since the reals are dense-in-themselves (i.e., between any two reals, there exists another real), there must exist some $\epsilon > 0$ (take, for example, $0< \epsilon = \frac{a-b}{2}$) such that $0 < \epsilon < a - b$. Thus, $b + \epsilon < a,$ this is a contradiction.